# Mongoose populating subdocument to subdocument

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've got a complex Mongoose population issue that I'm trying to sort out, and wondered if someone could shed some light (yeah yeah, I know, could use a RDBMS, but most the other bits of the schema lend themselves nicely to Mongo).

I've got two models: a `Study` and a `Participant`.

Study:

```
var StudySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  checklist: [
    {
      order: Number,
      text: String
    }
  ]
});
```

Participant:

```
var ParticipantSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  checklist_items: [
    {
      isComplete: Boolean,
      item: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

When a participant is created (they're always part of a study), the checklist is copied over onto the participant, so we can keep track of that checklist on the individual participant. I'm simply pushing IDs into the `Participant.checklist_items.item` to link those back to the items on the Study. (These are referenced, not wholesale copied, so that text changes to the study checklist are propagated down naturally)

I want to populate this model when retrieving a participant. When I get them, I want `item` on `checklist_items` to be populated with the corresponding item from the study. Hope that makes sense.

I've tried things like:

```
Participant.findById(req.params.id)                                    
    .populate({path: 'checklist_items.item', populate: {model: 'Study', path: 'checklist'})                                           
    .exec()
```

But no dice. I've monkeyed around with this for awhile, and I'm not sure I'm grokking how to do this child-to-child type population.

Any ideas? Is this possible?

Edit: clarified title with correct terms

Answer (score 1):

It appears this isn't possible with Mongoose, and represents a bit of antipattern. Leaving a reference to this issue for folks with this question in the future: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2772

Comment: This feature has been implemented in a later version of Mongoose.  Works for me using v5.5.5

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try this:

```
Participant.findById(req.params.id)                                    
    .populate({path: 'checklist_items.item', model: 'Study'})                                           
    .exec()
```

This will fetch you required`participant` and `populate` all the `item` inside `checklist_items`.

See if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It doesn't quite work, since I don't want to populate with Study objects, but a sub-object that's part of the Study object (items in the `study.checklist` array).

So, with the query you'd recommended, mongo issues a query like this: `studies.findOne({ _id: ObjectId('XXX')})`, when what I really want it to do is find the sub-objects, not the study itself. Now that I write that out, I realize this may be a) not possible, and b) the wrong way to go about it altogether.